# Ext Js 6.0.0 remove table's small red dirty cell flags manually

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a table where I can change cell data, afterwards I manually trigger an AJAX PUT request with that changed data. The 'table' is extending an `Ext.grid.Panel` . After the request returned successfully I want the red flags of the changed cells to disappear.

[image: red dirty flag]

```
// some ID actually passed from somewhere else
var myEntityId = '123456';    

Ext.Ajax.request( {
  url: '/myEntity/'+ myEntityId,
  method: 'PUT',
  params: { pressure: 47 },
  success: function( response, opts ) {
    // remove red cell flags of the table...
  },
});
```

How do I do that?

(The post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905922/845117 did not really help me. At the position where the code runs I do not really have a store connected to my table cells. Plus I send more informations to the backend than are simply displayed in the table. This also reasons why I use an extra ajax request for updating the backend.)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use `record.commit()` to commit a record without syncing it to the backend.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2glo

Comment: Alexander, thank you for the hint! I had to get hold of the record variable and invoke `record.commit()`. It works.

As in your example shown I could not use the listener `checkchange` since it did not existing for my column; probably another ExtJs version.

Comment: Yes, your column is not a `checkcolumn`, but the how to get the record still holds for all other grid events as well (the record is usually a parameter to the event). I used a checkcolumn so I could keep the example as small as possible, since all other column types require at least an editing plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You do have a store connected to the grid - that's how the grid works. It's just that the store isn't connected to a Proxy, and that's absolutely fine.

The cells are flagged because the store thinks those records are unsaved. To clear the flags, you need to change what the store thinks. You can do this with the `commitChanges` method on the Store object. e.g.:

```
success: function( response, opts ) {
  grid.getStore().commitChanges();  
},
```

Alternatively, you can hide the red flags altogether by configuring the grid not to show them. You do this by providing a `viewConfig` to the grid when constructing or initialising it:

```
viewConfig: { showDirty: false }
```